# How to add different MediaTypeFormatters for different controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In the new ASP.NET Web Api you can hookup MediaTypeformatters to a controller like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    config.Formatters.Add(new ContactPngFormatter());
    config.Formatters.Add(new VCardFormatter());
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{id}/{ext}", // URL with parameters
        new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

But this is a "global" configuration. What if I want a different set of MediaTypeFormatters for a specific controller. How would I create a specific configuration for that?

Comment: IMO, nobody will answer your question unless you go and accept some answers on your earlier questions.

Comment: It would be exceptionally nice if you would mark some of the answers you've received as accepted.